# Dual Boot Windows (any Version) + Linux (any Distribution) with GPT/UEFI, full system encryption and shared partitions

Tags: multi-boot, truecrypt, uefi, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I didn't think that my requiremetns were too special, but my search really didn't yield too many results, so I still got some quesitons unanswered.

Basically I'm getting new hardware and will do a complete re-install on my system. As my new Mainboard features UEFI (as they all do now), I wanted to switch - but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to fullfill my requirements:

- I need to dual-Boot windows and Linux. Preferrably Windows 7 (x64) Professional and a Debain based System (*ubuntu), but I have access to Windows 8.1, too, and any Distribution will do (though that shouldn't make too much difference)
- I need full system encryption. That is, the linux system partition, windows system partition and all data partitions have to be fully encrypted.
- I have shared data partitions, that need to be readable and writable from both systems
- No need to get TPM / secure boot working, my mainboard doesn't feature TPM anyway.
- As a bonus, I want to enter my encryptionpassword only once if possible

My current system uses LUKS for Linux System Encryption and Truecrypt for Windows System encryption and shared partitions. That way, I only have to enter the password once at system startup in Windows (pre-boot authentication as truecrypt calls it), and only once in Linux (for LUKS - the password is stored in the kernel keyring and used in truecrypt scripts I added to upstart, works like a charme once I had the scripts working)

Unfortunately, the Truecrypt bootloader cannot handle GPT yet. So there are 3 Alternatives

- Using Legacy Boot and my current setup
- Not encrypting Windows System partition (don't want that, as it keeps sensitive files stored in AppData or ProgramData or wherever else Windows hides files unencrypted)
- Using Bitlocker + LUKS.

The Last setup looks like it could work, but bitlocker support for Linux is pretty beta atm, and there seems no easy way to auto-mount bitlocker encrypted partitions. So the only really working solution would be bitlocker for windows system, luks for linux system and truecrypt for shared partition, but that requires a second password prompt in windows to mount the truecrypt volumes + plus it's a pain to set up.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: If you want to use Truecrypt then you cannot use GPT which means you must enable legacy boot support.  This alone isn't a problem.  The only thing you lose is the GPT partition support, which limits you to MBR, which limits your ability to use 3TB+ large disks.  You seem to understand what you actually want to do is not possible, so I am confused, what is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, it IS possible, combining Bitlocker, LUKS and Truecrypt. (Truecrypt is able to use GPT btw, just not for system drives, because it only features a MBR bootloader).

My question is, if anybody knows any setup I might have missed (through software I don't know or any development I might have missed), any way to auto-mount bitlocker in Linux or any way to get the "three encryption systems mixture" setup work a little less annoying.

Comment: Here's some info: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9528.how-to-multiboot-with-bitlocker-tpm-and-a-non-windows-os.aspx

Comment: I also have this problem - Windows 10 and Linux Mint on separate partitions of an SSD, with a separate HDD for data shared by both.

Comment: @DavidHeyman I went for my old approach (Truecrypt + LUKS) without UEFI boot. WIndows installed on an MBR parted disk (which you should be able to do on your SSD, doubt it's larger than 3TB) and encrypted by Truecrypt, Linux encrypted with LUKS, data encrypted with Treucrypt. However Obviously legacy boot requires more boot time than UEFI on modern systems, so the benefits yu get from booting from an SSD might get nullified by that.